# How to send an image to a flask server using Postman

Tags: python, postman, flask-restful

I need to send an image file to a flask server using Postman.I did send it  using a web browser and "render template".But when i tried the same program with postman it showed `"method not allowed"`

[image: Postman 405].

I also tried /upload, but it says `"bad request"`

[image: Postman 400]

Comment: Where have you saved the file? In case I need to upload a file from some random location, how do i pass the path here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To make this work you'll need this:

- add *upload* in your URL in postman.
- add header Content-Type multipart/form-dataitem
- enter file as key for row in form data where you choose your file. On the screenshots I see that it is empty.

Comment: Try adding header *Content-Type* *multipart/form-data*

Comment: You should also enter *file* as key for row in form data where you choose your file. On the screenshots I see that it is empty.

Comment: Thanks John .Sorry for the late reply.I just ran the program.I was missing the key .So i added "file" and it worked.Damn that was a simple mistake.

Comment: Content-Type was the missing part!! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

to run your code on postman you need to do some changes
in the **header** section change the 
 -  "content-type" : "multipart/form-data"

[image]
and in the **body** section select
"form-data" : and choose file

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue testing flask API with file upload in postman. I was passing both String data and Image file in one flask API.

Tried `Content-Type = multipart/form-data` and `Content-Type = application/json` but it didn't work.

Resolved it by removing all `Content-Type` headers. Strangely it works that way.

Hope this helps if anyone stuck in the similar issue.